# Does this function have improper integral but not Lebesgue integral?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R\to R}$ defined by $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1,\text{ if } x\geq 0\\ -1,\text{ if } x<0\end{cases}$.Clearly for this function, $f^+=\begin{cases} 1,\text{ if } x\geq 0\\ 0,\text{ if } x<0\end{cases}$ and $f^-=\begin{cases} 0,\text{ if } x\geq 0\\ 1,\text{ if } x<0\end{cases}$.So,$\int_\mathbb R f^+(x) d\lambda(x)=+\infty$ and $\int_\mathbb R f^-(x)d\lambda(x)=+\infty$,So,$f$ is not Lebesgue integrable i.e. $\int_\mathbb R |f(x)|d\lambda(x)=+\infty$ but I think this function is improper Riemann integrable because $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx=0$ as signed area under the graph of $f$ is $0$.Is my conclusion correct or I am making some error?

Comment: $f$ is not improperly integrable, either. What you are looking for is the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of the integral.

Comment: @geetha290krm sorry for the typo